# X is a binomial random variable, then is aX+b follows a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

I know when X ~ N(mu, sigma^2), then aX+b follows normal distribution.
But I'm curious when it happens to binomial random variable.
And I don't intuitively understand how multiply constant to binomial random variable.

Could anyone help me to understand.
Thanks in advance.